# Watson Discovery Service: Query Options

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson, watson-discovery

Is it possible to add a threshold for passage_score in the query_options? here is my query_options in python:

```
 query_options = {'query': {query,'passage_score>20'},'passages': 'true'}
```

which is not working. I was able to set a threshold for document score and also for relevance of entities but not for passage_score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This capability is not supported, however it would be pretty easy in a client application to simply filter the output of the passages by score.

You *are* able to tweak the number of passages that are returned so it will always return the top n passages (n=1-100). Which I think is what you want to do anyway, since the passage score is specific to the query, and is not a normalized score that should be used to compare against others.